# Can't we write some answers as which happened to be a comment if we don't have enough reputation

Tags: feature-request

My thoughts are like by putting Disclaimer or some kind of comment tag which converts our answer in comment
without spamming the question..

Comment: Answers are called "answers" for a reason.

Comment: Why would they add functionality to automatically convert the answer into a comment, when the restriction against comments is there for a *reason*? Seems kind of pointless.

Answer (score 6):

If you're not answering the question, why are you bothering?  One should really only use comments for clarification, and answers for actually answering the question.

If the question isn't clear enough for you to answer in its current state without *some* kind of comment, that would be a good signal for you to flag it for closure until the OP can fix their issues.  You only want to answer questions which are clear and concise.

Comment: Still, what's someone to do who knows they can provide the answer if the OP can just clarify one little point?

Comment: @MrLister Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: @MrLister get rep otherwise, by answering clear questions/asking good ones/editing content. Once you CAN comment, you do.